# Interface which contains conj?

Tags: clojure, deftype

As an exercise, I am developing a data structure similar to Vector. I have implemented all interfaces which IPersistentVector extends, but I have not found the interface where 'conj' is defined. Which interface is that? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`clojure.lang.IPersistentCollection/cons`. It was named `cons` originally, and that's stuck around in the interface even though the Clojure function for it is now called `conj`.

Comment: Another example is `rest` which is `c.l.ISeq/more` on the interface side.